# Count duplicate values in an array and return count with an additional value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, duplicates

I've got the following `array` and I'd like to return a new array containing the count of the duplicate `id`s along with the value of the `id`:

```
const things = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Something',
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Another thing',
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 1'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Yet another thing',
    categoryId: 2,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 2'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'One more thing',
    categoryId: 4,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 3'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Last thing',
    categoryId: 4,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 3'
  }
]
```

I've managed to put together a simple function that returns the count of duplicate `id`s (see below), but it also return the `id` (i.e. `1, 2, 4`):

```
function categoriesCount (things) {
  const thingsMapped = things.map(thing => thing.categoryId)
  return thingsMapped.reduce((map, val) => {
    map[val] = (map[val] || 0) + 1
    return map
  }, {})
}
```

`console.log('categoriesCount', categoriesCount(things))`

Returns:

```
"categoriesCount" Object {
  1: 2,
  2: 1,
  4: 2
}
```

Whereas I'd like it to return:

```
"categoriesCount" Object {
  'Category 1': 2,
  'Category 2': 1,
  'Category 3': 2
}
```

**Note:** the category title's numeric value (e.g. Category **3**) may not match it's `id` value (e.g. `4` with regards to Category 3).

What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the last 2 objects' title be "Category 4" to get that output?

Comment: Is the key the category label or a generic "Category " label followed by the categoryId?

Comment: Replace all instances of `map[val]` with `map['Categories ' + val]`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take `categoryTitle` directly without mapping the array before.

```js
function categoriesCount (things) {
    return things.reduce((hash, { categoryTitle }) => {
        hash[categoryTitle] = (hash[categoryTitle] || 0) + 1;
        return hash;
   }, {});
}

const things = [{ id: 1, title: 'Something', categoryId: 1, categoryTitle: 'Category 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'Another thing', categoryId: 1, categoryTitle: 'Category 1' }, { id: 3, title: 'Yet another thing', categoryId: 2, categoryTitle: 'Category 2' }, { id: 4, title: 'One more thing', categoryId: 4, categoryTitle: 'Category 3' }, { id: 5, title: 'Last thing', categoryId: 4, categoryTitle: 'Category 3' }]

console.log(categoriesCount(things));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: categoryTitle seems somewhat wrong considering the output. It looks like (though it doesn't make much sense) he needs to concatenate a generic label category with the categoryId.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do that in a single [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) shot, using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to acquire the desired categoryTitle and to build the key accordingly.

The following code assumes the categoryTitle is consistent along the records and that you want to group by categoryTitle.
If you don't want do to such, please specify that.

```js
const things = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Something',
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Another thing',
    categoryId: 1,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 1'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Yet another thing',
    categoryId: 2,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 2'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'One more thing',
    categoryId: 4,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 3'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Last thing',
    categoryId: 4,
    categoryTitle: 'Category 3'
  }
];

const res = things.reduce((acc, {categoryTitle}) => {
   return acc[categoryTitle] = (acc[categoryTitle] || 0) + 1, acc;
}, {});
console.log('categoriesCount', res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `map` function is not needed, and what is missing is to use the attr `categoryTitle` as key:

```js
const things = [  {    id: 1,    title: 'Something',    categoryId: 1,    categoryTitle: 'Category 1'  },  {    id: 2,    title: 'Another thing',    categoryId: 1,    categoryTitle: 'Category 1'  },  {    id: 3,    title: 'Yet another thing',    categoryId: 2,    categoryTitle: 'Category 2'  },  {    id: 4,    title: 'One more thing',    categoryId: 4,    categoryTitle: 'Category 3'  },  {    id: 5,    title: 'Last thing',    categoryId: 4,    categoryTitle: 'Category 3'  }];
function categoriesCount (things) {
  return things.reduce((map, {categoryTitle}) => {
    map[categoryTitle] = (map[categoryTitle] || 0) + 1;
    return map
  }, {})
}

console.log('categoriesCount', categoriesCount(things))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The category title doesn't always match the `categoryId`, e.g. `Category 3` has an `id` of `4`, so what you've suggested would result in `'Category 4': 2`, whereas I'm after `'Category 3': 2`, so the full category title, not one derived from the `id`.

Comment: @NeilMerton your original example suggested the opposite though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Category Title will be consistent

```
function categoriesCount (things) {
const thingsMapped = things.map(thing => thing.categoryId)
  return thingsMapped.reduce((map, val) => {
    map[val] = (map[val] || 0) + 1
    return map
  }, {})
}
```